# Apache: redirecting users, but keep same path?

Tags: apache

I want to be able to redirect users to a different TLD but keep the same path:

For example if the user goes to:

```
example.com/cars/10
```

Using apache how can I redirect the user to something like:

```
my_new_site.com/cars/10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server, you can place this into your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my_new_site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: NB more modern versions of Apache have no \  before the . in the RewriteCond line

Answer (score 4):

use a 302 redirect in your config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect /cars http://my_new_site.com/cars/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need more flexibility, you can use mod_rewrite, and then use those rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://my_new_site.com/$1 [NC]
```

There's a nice [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) at apache.org.