# redirecting an url to another url with the same path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Suppose I have to different domains:

```
sub.domain.com
```

and

```
example.com
```

Now I want to redirect `sub.domain.com` to `example.com` with the same path. For example if I have the path `sub.domain.com/the-path` I want it to redirect to `example.com/the-path`
I saw this: [Apache: redirecting users, but keep same path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517811/apache-redirecting-users-but-keep-same-path) but it is now working!
Both of urls point to one folder in one server but I want `sub.domain.com` to be redirected to `example.com`. With the code bellow in the .htaccess file, it redirects only for the base page meaning `sub.domain.com/` and for the other paths, it is not woring

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What Should I do?

Comment: There's no reason why that would only redirect http://sub.domain.com and not http://sub.domain.com/foo.  RewriteLog (2.2) or LogLevel rewrite:trace8 would clear it up.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: It worked! I just moved it some lines upward! Actually I had another rule which overwrited this rule!